# How to integrate Sina Weibo login into wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, weibo, sinaweibo

How can I integrate a login using Sina Weibo in my wordpress site, just like we do for facebook and twitter ?

Comment: Have you looked at http://open.weibo.com/wiki/Oauth/en?

Comment: Why does this have four upvotes? It's not a debugging question at all...

Comment: @Lee Not all questions on Stack Overflow solely have to be about debugging. Think of it as for programming: debugging is not the only aspect.

Comment: This question is being discussed on [SO Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300552/failed-a-review-audit-even-though-the-post-was-of-low-quality).

Answer (score 2):

The total integration process is 3 steps. You can find the process of integration from the below steps.

1. [Create a Sina Weibo Account](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~lingwang/weiboguide/#weiboacc): This is the normal account registration process.
2. [Set up Open Weibo Account and Register an Application](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~lingwang/weiboguide/#openweiboacc): To use the API you need *app client ID*, *app client secret*, *redirect uri*.
3. [Using the Sina Weibo API](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~lingwang/weiboguide/#clientapi)

If you have already having an account then you can directly skip to step 2.

If you cannot read mandrian you can follow the images displayed and the definition of the label is also displayed there.

[Source](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~lingwang/weiboguide/)